# Custom encryption Algo in Ecryptfs

Tags: cryptography, ecryptfs

has anyone used custom encryption algorithm(s) for encrypting data in `ecryptfs`?

Custom `Algorithm` means any other crypto `library/algorithm` than standard kernel crypto APIs used by `ecryptfs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found something.
Ecryptfs uses ciphers from native kernel crypto library for encryption/decryption operations. 
More specifically, it uses the generic "struct crypto_ablkcipher" (a kind of asynchronous block cipher) of crypto library. This shows strong coupling of crypto lib with ecryptfs.

So, if you want to use custom algorithm, then you may have to write one in kernel that should adapt to the interface of crypto library. If you need more information on this, please check 
[How can i add more algorithm in cryptoAPI in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364442/how-can-i-add-more-algorithm-in-cryptoapi-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

The list of available algorithms is [hardcoded](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/head:/src/libecryptfs/module_mgr.c#L583):

```
static struct cipher_descriptor {
    char *name;
    uint32_t blocksize;
    uint32_t min_keysize;
    uint32_t max_keysize;
} cipher_descriptors[] = {
    {"aes", 16, 16, 32},
    {"blowfish", 8, 16, 56},
    {"des3_ede", 8, 24, 24},
    {"twofish", 16, 16, 32},
    {"cast6", 16, 16, 32},
    {"cast5", 8, 5, 16},
    {NULL, 0, 0, 0}
};
```